# How spring transaction works in this example and how to resolve LazyInitializationException?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting **org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException** exception. What I know is, the issue is caused because I have fetched profile object in user entity lazily and before proxy object gets initialized the session is closed.

Is the session closed after executing findAll() method? Is there any other option to execute findAll() method and parse within a same transaction rather than parsing inside findAll() method?

I only wanted to know how spring transaction works when findAll method from service and later parse method of UserUtils class is called?

I also found that using propagation in @Transactional annotation will help. Will it? Please make me clear.

Now Let's look some codes.

**User.java**

```
package com.technep.test.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String name;

private String fatherName;

private String motherName;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_profile_id")
private Profile profile;
}
```

**Profile.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profile")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Profile {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="profile_name")
private String name;

@Column(name="created_date")
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name="last_modified_date")
private Date lastmodifiedDate;

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;


@GetMapping(value = "/api/users")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserResponseDTO>> getListOfUsers(){
    List<User> users = userService.findAll();
    List<UserResponseDTO> responseDTOs =UserUtils.parseUserToDTO(users);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<UserResponseDTO>>(responseDTOs,HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
public interface UserService {

User findById(Integer id);

List<User> findAll();

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@Override
public User findById(Integer id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public List<User> findAll() {
   return repository.findAll();
}

}
```

**UserUtils.java**

```
public class UserUtils {

public static List<UserResponseDTO> parseUserToDTO(List<User> users) {

    List<UserResponseDTO> responseDTOs  = new ArrayList<>();

    users.forEach(user -> {
        UserResponseDTO responseDTO = new UserResponseDTO();
        responseDTO.setId(user.getId());
        responseDTO.setName(user.getName());
        responseDTO.setProfileName(user.getProfile().getName());
        responseDTO.setProfileCreatedDate(user.getProfile().getCreatedDate());
        responseDTOs.add(responseDTO);
    });

    return responseDTOs;
}

}
```

The exception is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:147)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:260)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:68)
at com.technep.test.entity.Profile_$$_jvst12b_0.getName(Profile_$$_jvst12b_0.java)
at com.technep.test.utils.UserUtils.lambda$parseUserToDTO$0(UserUtils.java:27)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at com.technep.test.utils.UserUtils.parseUserToDTO(UserUtils.java:23)
at com.technep.test.controller.UserController.getListOfUsers(UserController.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you post your UserRepository code?

Comment: @locus2k done!!!

Comment: Thank you. Added some helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the session closed after executing findAll() method?

Yes.  By default any action on a repository is atomic.

> Is there any other option to execute findAll() method and parse within
>   a same transaction rather than parsing inside findAll() method?

Yes.  If you have @Transactional around the method doing both actions.  The transaction will stay open until that method returns.

> I only wanted to know how spring transaction works when findAll method
>   from service and later parse method of UserUtils class is called?

You have several options.

1. Add the `@Transactional` annotation getListOfUsers on the controller should work.
2. However you might consider having a service method that both searches for all the Users and creates the response.  You would want to put the `@Transactional` on this method instead.
3. A third option would be to create a named query that explicitly requests the Profiles to be eagerly fetched as part of the query.

I would say the 2nd or 3rd option are preferable over the first.

Comment: Do you have any idea about propagation of Transactional annotation?
Can't it be used to solve this issue?

Comment: The propagation is optional.  Sometimes you want to participate in a transaction that already exists or create a brand new transaction even if one already exists.  In your case, the default will be fine.

Comment: Likewise, I want to participate in the transaction that already exists. Won't it help me out? :D

Comment: If you have a GET mapping then you have a HTTP request coming in.  Therefore you are not in a transaction.  If you want to do other activities during the transaction then you would want to go with option 2, and put everything you want to do inside the service method.

Comment: Here is the information about the different propogation models: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you have a OneToOne on lazy fetch? Typical OneToOnes are not set that way. Lazy Loading is a design pattern which is used to defer initialization of an object as long as it’s possible and is typically used when fetching lists. With Hibernate the transaction is typically closed when a user tries to fetch the resource. I'd suggest removing the Lazy Fetch and try like that.

If you cant here are some other helpful suggestions you can try.

You can actually write a query in your `UserRepository` to fetch your Profiles something like as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT user FROM User user JOIN FETCH user.profile")
List<User> findAll();
```

This will override the built in findAll and fetch the list with the users profiles already eager fetched for you.

Another thing you can do is create a UserProfileRepository and fetch the profile once you got the user something like:

```
public interface UserProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<UserProfile, Integer>{
  Profile findById(Integer id);
}
```

Then in your DTO you can do something like this:

```
users.forEach(user -> {
    UserResponseDTO responseDTO = new UserResponseDTO();
    responseDTO.setId(user.getId());
    responseDTO.setName(user.getName());

    Profile profile = profileRepository.findById(user.getProfileId());        

    responseDTO.setProfileName(profile.getName());
    responseDTO.setProfileCreatedDate(profile.getCreatedDate());
    responseDTOs.add(responseDTO);
});
```

Comment: I used lazy fetching just to avoid internal joins when using HQL. For example: If I have many other objects mapped inside Profile entity then it might throw error as mysql can only use 61 joins when fetching the entity.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to fetch a `List<UserResponseDTO>` directly from the DB without first fetching entities and then converting them.

In your repository create a method:

```
@Query("select new com.company.UserResponseDTO(u.id, u.name, u.profile.name, u.profile.createdDate) from User u")
List<UserResponseDTO> findAllAsDTO();
```

Make sure your UserResponseDTO has an appropiate constructor which takes this arguments in this order.

This is the most efficient way. It saves memory by not fetching entities, which take addidional memory for dirty checking. Also this is more scalable since if someone adds attributes to User or Profile entity they wont affect this query. Finally this is also less code to write.

I recommend this approach.

This technique is called [JPQL Constructor Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to lazy load `profile` outside of transaction - hence the exception.

To resolve the problem you could map your entity to DTO inside `UserService` implementation. That seems to be the most suitable solution in your case.

You also may fetch `profile` eagerly or mark controller method as `@Trasnational` but it does not seem to be a good idea as controller does not contain any business logic.